# How to fetch email from Yii-eauth?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, lightopenid

I am using **Yii-eauth** for social login. https://github.com/Nodge/yii-eauth
Now i am getting username by

```
Yii::app()->user->name.
```

I want to fetch email opf user also . How to do this in Yii 1.1 . Thanx in advance

Comment: maybe `var_dump(Yii::app()->user);` could help

Comment: Did you create user record in db for this user?

Comment: what i am doing is fetching name and email and storing them in db

Comment: have a look at EAuthUserIdentity class line number 56. here you can set email also.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get email address from linkedin.

There is a class for LinkedIn Login

Change the `$scope` variable to get email address.

Also, do the settings in LinkedIn App page.

```
protected $scope = 'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress'; // 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress';
```

Also, add `email-address` to singed request like this:

```
$info = $this->makeSignedRequest('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,email-address,positions)', array(), false); // json format not working :(
        $info = $this->parseInfo($info);
```

Now, your `$info` will have `email-address` for you.

Facebook also has solution similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

In your **protected/componenets/UserIdentity.php** File you need to add user email to session like this way:-

```
 $this->setState('email_of_user',$users->email);
```

You can use and access this email_of_user variable via `echo Yii::app()->user->email_of_user`

If this code is not working for you then you need to do following changes in your files:-

In your **model/LoginForm.php** ,

replace this function,

```
public function actionLogin() {
        $serviceName = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('service');
        if (isset($serviceName)) {
            /** @var $eauth EAuthServiceBase */
            $eauth = Yii::app()->eauth->getIdentity($serviceName);
            $eauth->redirectUrl = Yii::app()->user->returnUrl;
            $eauth->cancelUrl = $this->createAbsoluteUrl('site/login');

            try {
                if ($eauth->authenticate()) {
                    //var_dump($eauth->getIsAuthenticated(), $eauth->getAttributes());
                    $identity = new EAuthUserIdentity($eauth);

                    // successful authentication
                    if ($identity->authenticate()) {
                        Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
                        //var_dump($identity->id, $identity->name, Yii::app()->user->id);exit;

                        // special redirect with closing popup window
                        $eauth->redirect();
                    }
                    else {
                        // close popup window and redirect to cancelUrl
                        $eauth->cancel();
                    }
                }

                // Something went wrong, redirect to login page
                $this->redirect(array('site/login'));
            }
            catch (EAuthException $e) {
                // save authentication error to session
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', 'EAuthException: '.$e->getMessage());

                // close popup window and redirect to cancelUrl
                $eauth->redirect($eauth->getCancelUrl());
            }
        }

        // default authorization code through login/password ..
    }
```

In your **protected/componenets/UserIdentity.php** file:-

replace this line

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
```

to

```
 class UserIdentity extends EAuthUserIdentity
```

Hope this code will work for you :)